# OpenFL - iOS - Tags for launcher screenshots in application.xml

Tags: ios, xml, haxe, openfl

So I've developed in OpenFL, app for iOS, and I want to compile it as so.

But apparently I can put tags in application.xml that indicate the path to `Default.png`, etc...

Can someone list those tags for me please? 
(I guess the icon only needs one `<icon .../>` tag? - which I already have.)

Answer (score 0):

Sample code from the [HaxeFlixel documentation](http://haxeflixel.com/documentation/ios/#project-xml-settings):

```
<set name="PRERENDERED_ICON" value="true" />

<icon path="Icon.png" size="57" if="ios" />
<icon path="Icon@2x.png" size="114" if="ios" />
<icon path="Icon-72.png" size="72" if="ios" />
<icon path="Icon-72@2x.png" size="144" if="ios" />

<launchImage path="Default.png" width="320" height="480" if="ios" />
<launchImage path="Default@2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
<launchImage path="Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024" if="ios" />
<launchImage path="Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048" if="ios" />
<launchImage path="Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768" if="ios" />
<launchImage path="Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536" if="ios" />
<launchImage path="Default-568h@2x.png" width="640" height="1136" if="ios" />
```

You should be able to adjust the `path` values to point to a subfolder, and the images will still end up in the right place. (Just don't change the filenames.)